# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src")

Tags: content-security-policy

I have the following lambda@edge code:

```
'use strict';

  exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Adding additional headers to CloudFront response.');
    let response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
    response.headers['strict-transport-security'] = [{
    key: 'Strict-Transport-Security',
    value: 'max-age=86400; includeSubdomains; preload',
    }];
    response.headers['x-content-type-options'] = [{
    key: 'X-Content-Type-Options',
    value: 'nosniff',
    }];
    response.headers['x-frame-options'] = [{
        key:   'X-Frame-Options',
        value: "DENY"
    }];
    response.headers['content-security-policy'] = [{
        key:   'Content-Security-Policy',
        value: "default-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; img-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; script-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; style-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com; object-src 'none'"
    }];
    response.headers['x-xss-protection'] = [{
        key:   'X-XSS-Protection',
        value: "1; mode=block"
    }];
    response.headers['referrer-policy'] = [{
        key:   'Referrer-Policy',
        value: "same-origin"
    }];
    callback(null, response);
  };
```

But on my page I still get

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline ("script-src").
The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
```

What is the correct way to fix these errors?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: What is "lambda@edge"?